# Joining Session ID's

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a login area for my customers.
They send me data using there userid as a ref and they can login and view what they have sent.

Now some of my customers have more than one website and more than 1 userID.

**Example :**

Martin's userid = MW001 for website www.martin.com
Martin's userid = MW002 for website www.thomas.com

Now once they login , there user id is stored in a session which i use to display data from a mysql DB.

Is there a way to store both userid's in a session and display different information based on what they choose.

**Example :**

Martin logins in using userid MW001 for website www.martin.com , he can now view all the data related to userid MW001

I want him now to have a option to select a link called " View other website " and it will load that data for userid MW002 and not MW001 anymore.

```
My DB Looks Like This :

userid , Name, Surname, Email, Tel, URL
```

**OK , what i need to know.**

I need to know how to move between sessions.

If my customer logins in user userid MW001 how will i load MW002 ?

Comment: Yes this is possible.

Comment: Can you recommend any articles i can read to get an example on this. Thanks

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking.  You can store as much information as you like in a session.  I think perhaps you need to be clearer about what part of this you already know how to do and what part you can't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did was just create a session, then join mysql tables and link the users that way. It was actually really simple.